# Acceleration of an object after a force has been applied to it

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, velocity, projectile

Suppose I launch an object with a force $F=ma$, does it, at the instant it leaves my hand, have the same acceleration $a$?

Generally, when I move something, do I give it velocity or acceleration?

Comment: When you push something you give it momentum and rate of change of this momentum is what is force you apply

Comment: Adding to the above suppose you have a block full of sand and you push it and also create a hole in it then what do you think you impart to the system I think it's momentum

Comment: Does its velocity correspond to the integral of the acceleration of the force applied at the instant it is no longer under it?

Comment: adding to it the acceleration due to gravity I guess

Comment: at the time it is launched it's velocity would be $\int \sum F/m$?

Comment: yes yes it is, thank you

Comment: For the second part of your problem see how do you define the contact between two particles it is the condition that normal force between the two objects should be greater than zero so now try to think a bit more on the problem

Comment: Acceleration "at the instant it leaves my hand" doesn't mean anything.  You can have *before* and *after* but not "at".   Acceleration measures a rate of change, so it makes sense only over a time interval.

Comment: $dt$ after it leaves my hand

Comment: $dt$ after it leaves your hand there is no more force, so $a=0$.  (Subject to several classical assumptions and idealizations.)

Comment: I should say more about those assumptions, but it would take more space than allotted.    For example,  consider that the object and your hand are made of atoms having a nucleus and electrons.  The "instant it leaves your hand" is not well defined.  Etc.

Comment: yeah well, we're talking about newtonian mechanics

Answer (score 0):

No, when the object just leaves your hand,the value of acceleration reduces to $0$ if there aren't any other forces acting upon the object.

However the velocity of the object continues to increase for so long as the force acts on the object. Also, during the time interval when the force was acting on the object, the value of acceleration $a$ would remain constant if your force was constant.

After your hand loses contact with the block, there is no more force acting on the object (considering ideal environment) so it should have an uniform velocity $v$.

But it is worth noticing that a finite amount of time will be required for the body to accelerate from $v \text{ to } v_1$ which is the time interval when you continue to apply force to the object.

Moreover when you apply a force to the object, you accelerate it because you applied a **net** force. Velocity (*change in velocity, to be more precise*) is just a consequence of the force which caused some acceleration.

Comment: Adding to it $g$ and accelerations due to other ambient forces right?

Comment: Its acceleration should be $\sum \frac{F}{m}$ right? So we add ambient forces' accelerations to mine right?

Comment: yes you should vectorially add them

Comment: but isn't my hand under ambient forces' influence? so isn't $g$ and co already in my $a$?

Comment: What do you actually mean by ambient force?

Comment: Air resistance for example

Comment: Yes, you have to account for that in the real world.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so in Newtonian mechanics, "influence" is to be captured in the notion of a *force*. This means that you influence an object via applying a force to it--due to this force, the object experiences an acceleration which is determined by the second law of Newton. This acceleration, which is literally the rate of change of the velocity, determines how the velocity of the object changes. Here, the acceleration experienced by the object at an instant of time is determined purely by the force acting on it at that instant. There is no way to influence an object so that it attains a certain velocity at the same instant it gets influenced--see this in contrast to the fact that an object will instantaneously attain a certain value of acceleration at the same moment it is influenced. So, yes, in principle, you impart acceleration to objects when you act on them and you do not directly impart velocities.

That said, if you impart a "very large" force over a period of "very short" time, in effect, when you look at the behavior of the object over resolutions of time which are insensitive to the scales of time over which you applied the large force, it would look as if the influence directly induced a velocity in the object. Such influences are talked about in mechanical engineering or applied mechanics and go by the name of "[impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics))".

Comment: "by the force acting on it at that instant." not forces? i.e gravity and air resistance in the case of a thrown ball for example

Comment: @Luyw Yes, by "force", I mean the net force. So, if you are counting individual forces separately then, yes, you can replace "force" with "forces" everywhere in my answer.

Comment: but, in the same ball example, isn't my hand under the influence of such forces? so isn't $a$ the already "influenced" acceleration?

Comment: I am not familiar be with the concept of influence in the context of mechanics. What is is it?

Comment: @my2cts I didn't mean to imply it's standard terminology. I just used it to refer to the "physical effect of an interaction of a body with another body/bodies upon the said body". Force would be the quantitative measure of this influence -- in the same way mass is the quantitative measure of the inertia of a body.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration acts continuously when a continuous  force is applied. $F=ma$  means the more time  it is applied on the body the higher the acquired velocity. A simple example of F=ma is the fall from a height, starting with velocity zero:  The higher the body is released the  the more velocity it has acquired when it hits the ground.

Instantaneous force, as the one you describe for a launch, is an impulse, $F= dp/dt$ which lasts for a small dt. So the acceleration is for a small time interval, and the velocity acquired at the end of that, if in space away from gravitational fields, remains constant . On the earth the velocity will be diminished by friction with the air  and the continuous force of gravity up to the highes point. The  gravitational solution a parabola, where at the turning point it will be accelerating by the gravitational force [towards the ground.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion)

[image: parabwater]

A natural launch of water, each $Δ(m)$ gets a velocity due to the acceleration from the pressure at the output,  and follows a parabolic trajectory.

Comment: F=ma doesn't directly imply any change at all in the magnitude of velocity ("the more time it is applied the higher the velocity" is not always true). Consider centripetal acceleration, which constantly changes the velocity, but not the speed.